# How to put Array[Row] into JSON string

Tags: arrays, json, scala, apache-spark

I have `Array[Row]` called `arr` (I obtained it after `df.collect()`) that I want to pass in my JSON string as `key` and `value` pairs:

```
val result = """{"field1": "A", "arr": [""" + arr + """]}"""
```

It should be:

```
{"field1": "A", "arr": [
       {"name":"Ford", "model": "Fiesta"},
       {"name":"Ford", "model": "Mustang"},
       ...
]}
```

If I do it the way that I showed above, it will not work.

Should I iterate over this array and manually define each parameter?:

```
arr.get(i).get(arr.get(i).fieldIndex("field1")).toString()
```

Comment: Why don't you use `to_json` (with Dataframes) or `toJSON` with RDDs? What does the result of `df.collect()` look like ?

Comment: @philantrovert: If I do `df.toJSON`, then it returns `Dataset[String]`. What do I do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing as below by using `.toJSON` as suggested by *philantrovert* in comments of the question

```
val result = """{"field1":"A","arr":"""+df.toJSON.collectAsList()+"""}"""
```

If you are using `arr` variable then you can do

```
val arr = df.toJSON.collectAsList()
val result = """{"field1":"A","arr":"""+arr+"""}"""
```